GitHub API Calls Failing After Certain Period of Time
I am running a Jenkinsfile using a bash script, and for the first 6,000 API calls, I am getting the expected results, but then I get a 401 error. I cannot seem to figure this out. My token has 15,000 API calls; is it timing out. Can someone assist with this, please.
I tried sleeping after 6,000 requests, and I am still getting the same error.

check rate limit, The rate limit for GITHUB_TOKEN is 1,000 requests per hour per repository.
https://docs.github.com/en/rest/using-the-rest-api/rate-limits-for-the-rest-api?apiVersion=2022-11-28
also please provide some details or screenshots to help you better

What token are you using? It sounds like it is a short lived token that expires before the job completes. How long does it take to send 6,000 requests?
